# How to validate Jwt token?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I was exploring Spring security through two tutorials. In one of the tutorials jwt token is validated [as follows](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/blob/1b77669e0ca326b1c556a83dc0c3bae233653788/spring-social/src/main/java/com/example/springsocial/security/TokenProvider.java#L46):

```
public boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(appProperties.getAuth().getTokenSecret()).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
        return true;
    } catch (SignatureException ex) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT signature");
    } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Invalid JWT token");
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Expired JWT token");
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
        logger.error("Unsupported JWT token");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        logger.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

while in another tutorial, it is validated [as follows](https://github.com/koushikkothagal/spring-security-jwt/blob/d8ef76d8229cd6f5576b834b456a0086842272c7/src/main/java/io/javabrains/springsecurityjwt/util/JwtUtil.java#L51):

```
public String extractUsername(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
}

public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
    return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
}

public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
    final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
    return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
}
private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
}

private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
    return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
}

public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
    final String username = extractUsername(token);
    return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
}
```

I have few doubts:

**Q1.** The second example does no catch exceptions. Should catching and logging exceptions ideally be part of validation or not? Or the second example is indeed doing something similar which I am not able to spot?

**Q2.** Token expiry is handled by catching `ExpiredJwtException`, whereas second example explicitly checks for token expiry with `isTokenExpired()`. How it should be ideally done?

**Q3.** Second example explicitly checks whether `username` in token is indeed same as the username in the current security context with `username.equals(userDetails.getUsername())`. I dont know how it wont be, as I believe security context itself will be populated using current token. Thus I feel that this condition will always be trivially true. Am I correct? Also is this the reason why first example is not checking explicitly for this?

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are faulty since both of them are implementing custom security which in general is bad practice.

Writing a custom validation of something as important as tokens is not needed if you are using spring security since spring security has had full JWTSupport for several years now.

The documentation has an entire chapter on how to configure the built in `JWTFilter` that comes with spring security, and its as easy as just adding one single line.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Standard enabling of the jwt filter:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    return http.build();
}
```

Configure how your jwt should be verified:

```
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(this.key)
            .jwsAlgorithm(RS512).build();
}
```

There are several other things to configure.

Comment: Those articles may be doing custom security simply because they are old and necessary API might not be available then. Can you please point to any article which explains how to do it right way using latest APIs? (These two articles come in are top searches when googled for OAuth + spring boot ! ). Also what "several other" things are there to configure?

Comment: Spring security added JWT support in 2017. The top blog posts if you google are from 2020-2022, and its because they, like you, just doesnt seem to want ro read the official docs. I linked to the spring security docs, thats all you need, why cant you read them? Also asking for links to libraries blogs and tutorials is forbidden on stack overflow. Read the rules

Comment: Glad you pointed in precise direction!! Surprisingly all articles (except one) that I came across does not seem to follow doc way. I was guessing why that one article is doing it differently. May be because am just starting up with the topic. Experienced eyes like yours are more aware of the topic. I did read docs (especially [architectural](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html)), but not the oauth resource server page. I read non-doc articles first and they didnt say anything about "resource server", so I skipped the corresponding pages from doc 

Comment: resource server is the official name of it in the oauth2 rfc specification of a service that receives tokens. Most people that write blogs havnt read any specs or read any docs, they just read other blogs and then write their own.

Answer (score 0):

The second example does no catch exceptions. Should catching and logging exceptions ideally be part of validation or not? Or the second example is indeed doing something similar which I am not able to spot?

According to me we should catch exceptions and should be wrapped in business exceptions with error codes because it becomes easier to troubleshoot .